# Deleting records from tables which is mentioned in another driving table

Tags: teradata

I have a requirement like this in teradata.One table(Table A) consist of 3 columns like below

```
Table_Name||Last_Updated_Timestamp||Update_Flag
```

I need to write a query to delete all the records from those tables which is found in Table A.

Can anybody please help me?

Comment: Please add some information about what you have already tried, and what problems you have encountered while doing so.

Comment: `DELETE FROM tgt WHERE (Table_Name,Last_Updated_Timestamp,Update_Flag) IN (SELECT Table_Name,Last_Updated_Timestamp,Update_Flag FROM src)`?

Answer (score 0):

We do this in work with something we call SQL4SQL.

In BTEQ we export the result of statement:

select
 'delete from ' || Table_Name || ' all;'
from Table A;

and than we run the exported file with .RUN BTEQ command.